# Python 3.6 Dataframe Sorting by DateTime column [10:00:01 comes before 00:00:01]

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, datetime, python-3.6

Thank you in advance for any advice. I have searched all over and could not find a solution.

I would like to sort a dataframe by a TIME column formated as "%H:%M:%S".

```
df_VFT['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_VFT['DATE'])
pd.to_datetime(df_VFT.TIME, format="%H:%M:%S")
df_VFT['WEEK'] = df_VFT['DATE'].dt.year.map(str) + "-" + df_VFT['DATE'].dt.week.map(str)
df_VFT.sort_values(['TIME'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
print(df_VFT)
```

However, the resulting dataframe has the TIME column sorted almost correctly, but starting with 10:00:01. So sorting is 10:00:01 to 23:59:59, followed by 0:00:01 to 9:59:59.

First few rows of resulting dataframe

[image: First few rows of resulting dataframe]

Last few ros of resulting dataframe

[image: Last few ros of resulting dataframe]

How can I correct this so that the time when sorted starts with 00:00:01?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: i dont test, but I believe you need to set on `df_VFT.TIME` the return of `pd.to_datetime(df_VFT.TIME, format="%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: You are right. Thank you!